# Preview of text behind a link

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to display a "preview" of whats behind a link using css and html?

For instance: i have some textual information behind a link, but i want to show a part of this text beside the link... is it possible to do so without manually writing it down?

Here is the code example

```
<dl>
<dt>News</dt>
<dd></dd>
<a href=".html"><img src=".jpg" height=100 width=120/>Some text</a>
    <p>This is the text i want to use as a preview of whats behind the active href link</p>
</dl>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get something like `watermarks`?

Comment: Im not sure i know what watermarking is

Comment: Have you seen faded texts behind some official documents, like the name of a company usually being printed in a semi-transparent color on A4 papers? That's watermarking. Still didn't get it? Google for *watermark samples*. ;)

Comment: No i got it. But thats not quite what i was thinking about. Ill show you some code example instead

Comment: I think he is refering more to a "tool-tip" so to speak. Like how when you hover over a name it says their reputation, only this would show a snippet of text from the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS, set the element containing the link (`dd` in your case—the markup `<dd></dd>` must be a typo, the end tag should appear after the content, the `a` and `p` elements) to be relatively positioned. Set `display: none` for the `p` element but when hovered, make it absolutely positioned (which really means that it will be positioned relatively to the enclosing element) and turn it to visible. Add suitable background, border, and other stuff. The details depend on the context. The following would be one possibility if the `img` elements all use images that are 100px tall (so that 108px or something that is a suitable displacement for the `p` element).

```
<style>
dd p {
  display: none; }
dd {
  position: relative; }
dd:hover p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 108px;
  background: #ffd;
  color: black;
  border: solid gray 0.08em;
  padding: 0 0.2em;
  z-index: 1000;
  max-width: 20em;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Overlapping and displaying through can be done via CSS properties `z-index` and `opacity`. However, you have to use **absolute positioning** to stack elements on each other.

Comment: I think it's better if you first upload an image or a sketch of what you have in mind, then I'm sure we can solve it together ;).

Answer (score 0):

every link can have a tool-tip easily added to the link

```
<a href="/users/811785/saeed" title="5623 reputation" class="comment-user">Saeed</a>
```

use the `title` attribute to add your 'preview' so that when someone mouse's over a link and hovers for a moment, they can see the tool-tip :)

Comment: if you want a preview, like google does with its search results, you can render the page in an ajax call and display it in a div that moves with your mouse, but thats a whole other can of worms....

Comment: I was more thinking without any hovering effects, just plain visible preview of whats behind the link...

Comment: well if the title attribute isnt enough (pure html/css), you'll have to use some javascript to get any kind of preview going.